# Maven compiler warnings and errors in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings, m2eclipse

I already asked the opposite [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808555/maven-m2e-enforces-its-own-compiler-settings-disable/8809090#8809090) but now I'm growing fond of Maven and would like to set compiler warnings in my pom that are actually mapped to the eclipse project, enabling eclipse to mark "wrong" lines with warnings.

I think(?) Maven already sets the tick to overwrite the default warnings per project, but then just copies the default values into the non default settings. Then it shouldn't be a big hasle for a plugin to e.g. set "Member can be static" to warn?

Which is the write plugin? I can't the the compiler plugin to have any options for this.

Comment: Good question. I suppose you need to raise a feature request for `m2elcipse` plugin to capture the maven output and duplicate it as project errors. Hudson already has come parsing code, as it highlights warnings and errors.

Comment: May I ask, who or what is Hudson? It sounds promising what you say, but I do not quite understand where to find the code you are talking about. Please enlight me.

Comment: [Hudson CI](http://www.hudson-ci.org/) will not help you so much: it is web application. But is has build-in functionality to [parse Maven output](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/43713289/parsed_console_output_1.JPG?version=1&modificationDate=1271216347000) – you can e-user their code if you want to improve `m2elcipse` plugin yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your question. For the warnings bit, you can override it using the `showWarnings` entity in the maven compiler plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: And this highlights warnings in the ecipse while writing the code or only when you really compile it with maven?

Comment: That's only when you are compiling through maven

Comment: Hm I somehow want to force everybody using the pom to use higher compiler warnings to ensure better code quality. But this isn't possible?