# Maven keeps messing up my java compiler and build path settings

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

What happens: My java compiler settings are reset from my custom jdk to default java se1.5
When it hapens: Everytime i click maven- update project ( in eclipse of course).

I think it has something to do with the update project settings checkbox. But i cannot find in  my pom the tags responsible for configuring my eclipse project. Any hints?

BTW i cannot just uncheck the box because the pom might have other settings vital for my project

EDIT: sorry for the delay, here is my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<!--    <parent> -->
<!--        <groupId>org.geomajas</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>geomajas-parent</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>1.0.9</version> -->
<!--    </parent> -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ne</groupId>
    <artifactId>projl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>TApp</name>
    <description>Test</description>
    <url>http://www.example.com/</url>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.geomajas</groupId>
                <artifactId>geomajas-backend</artifactId>
                <version>1.13.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.geomajas</groupId>
                <artifactId>geomajas-face-puregwt</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.geomajas.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>geomajas-plugin-geotools-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.geomajas.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>geomajas-plugin-rasterizing-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.geomajas.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>geomajas-widget-puregwt-core-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.geomajas</groupId>
                <artifactId>geomajas-dep</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.28</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Geomajas dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geomajas.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>geomajas-plugin-rasterizing</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geomajas</groupId>
            <artifactId>geomajas-puregwt-client-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geomajas</groupId>
            <artifactId>geomajas-testdata</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geomajas.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>geomajas-layer-geotools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geomajas.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>geomajas-layer-openstreetmap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geomajas.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>geomajas-layer-wms</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Google dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- External GWT libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gwt-dnd</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dnd</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging dependencies, delegate all to slf4j and use logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Run the application using "mvn jetty:run" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                        <baseResource implementation="org.mortbay.resource.ResourceCollection">
                            <!-- need both the webapp dir and location where GWT puts stuff -->
                            <resourcesAsCSV>${basedir}/src/main/webapp,${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</resourcesAsCSV>
                        </baseResource>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <reload>manual</reload>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <module>the.proj.App</module>
                    <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
                    <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
                    <disableClassMetadata>true</disableClassMetadata>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</hostedWebapp>
                    <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>

                <configuration>

                    <!-- Container configuration -->
                    <container>
                        <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                        <type>remote</type>
                    </container>

                    <!-- Configuration to use with the container -->
                    <configuration>
                        <type>runtime</type>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.remote.username>${dev.deploy.username}</cargo.remote.username>
                            <cargo.remote.password>${dev.deploy.password}</cargo.remote.password>
                            <cargo.remote.uri>${dev.deploy.uri}</cargo.remote.uri>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployer>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>org.geomajas</groupId>
                                <artifactId>geomajas-puregwt-showcase</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <properties>
                                    <context>showcase-pure-trunk</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </deployer>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!-- m2eclipse with embedded jetty -->
        <profile>
            <id>m2e</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>m2e.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.geomajas</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geomajas-jetty-runner</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwt-version}</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <properties>
                <gwt.compiler.skip>true</gwt.compiler.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>skipGwt</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>skipGwt</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <gwt.compiler.skip>true</gwt.compiler.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>selenium-tests</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>!skipSelenium</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Run the application using "mvn jetty:run" -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <webAppConfig>
                                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                            </webAppConfig>
                            <reload>manual</reload>
                            <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                            <stopKey>stop-jetty</stopKey>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-jetty</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <daemon>true</daemon>
                                    <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                                    <connectors>
                                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                                            <port>9080</port>
                                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                                        </connector>
                                    </connectors>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-jetty</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*TestInt.java</include>
                                        <include>**/IntTest*.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Geomajas</id>
            <name>Geomajas repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.geomajas.org/</url>
        </repository>

        <!-- uncomment if you want to use Geomajas snapshots, comment for faster builds -->

        <repository>
            <id>Geomajas-latest</id>
            <name>Geomajas snapshot repository</name>
            <url>http://apps.geomajas.org/nexus/content/groups/latest</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Geomajas</id>
            <name>Geomajas repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.geomajas.org/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <gwt-version>2.5.1</gwt-version>
        <gwt.compiler.skip>false</gwt.compiler.skip>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you set [the Java version in the pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html)?

Comment: What did you specify in eclipse? Show your pom.xml. What values are changed when you update the project?

Comment: when i update, the java library is set back to Java1.5 from whatever i set it to. And my java compliance level is also set to Java 1.5

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8808555/1448212

Answer (score 9):

I am not quite sure about your problem but I believe m2e plugin get the source/output version by setting of compiler plugin.

In your POM, have something like

```
....
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
      .....
  </plugins>
</build>
```

m2e should be able to configure your Eclipse according to the source and target version

Comment: I agree with this. Unless you mention your project specific source, target version in pom.xml, m2e will read the parent pom settings and you may see that it's getting reset to different Java version