# How to configure compiler level (1.6) in maven settings.xml?

Tags: java, maven-3

I am familiar with configuring maven-compiler-plugin to use java 1.6 in pom.xml and using parent pom file.

Is there a way to configure java compiler level to java 1.6 in the settings.xml level (so that all my maven projects will use java 1.6)?

In this thread [default maven compiler setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531650/default-maven-compiler-setting) somebody told there is a way to configure it in settings.xml. 
Can someone please explain how to configure?

PS: Another way to specify Java compiler level:

```
<properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

-Siva

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer No. In the settings file you don't configure things like this, cause it doesn't make sense and would make your builds not reproducible. The information about configuring the [compiler plugin in settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) is rubbish.

Comment: So there is no such an option. Either I should have a parent pom with this configuration or copy-paste the maven-compiler-plugin config(very bad option :-)) for every project.

Comment: The best is to have a parent pom in particular a company or project-group pom which contains such configurations.

Answer (score 0):

source/target level can be configured in settings.xml, like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-1.6</id>
      <activation>
          // can be replaced with other conditions
          <jdk>1.6</jdk>
      </activation>
      <properties>
          <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
          <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
          <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>1.6</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
      </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```