# Eclipse JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm using Eclipse EE 3.7 with m2e plugin installed. I have JDK7 set in eclipse.
When I import maven projects, the JRE is set to `JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]`, So i have compilation issues with java 6 related stuff. Instead I want the JRE in eclipse to be by default set to JRE `System Library [J2SE-1.6]`

When i try to open a new project in eclipse File -> new -> Java project on the first screen i have an option to choose JRE and the third option is `Use default JRE (currently 'jdk1.7.0_03')`

From this i can see that the default JRE in Eclipse is 1.7, but when i import new Maven projects, the JRE is set to 1.5 by default.

Any help, how can i do this?

Comment: I am experiencing a similary problem.  Whatever the JRE System Library is set to, performing a Project>Maven>Update Project... resets the JRE System Library to J2SE-1.5.

Comment: Old question but still helpful in 2019 since it happens also in current SpringBoot 2 projects.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The problem is not with Eclipse, but with the projects you're importing. m2e will set the project's JRE to match the maven project. The POM specifies the JRE version, and this is defaulted to 1.5 if not present. You need this in the POM:

```
<build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                   <source>1.7</source>
                   <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: [Here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html) is some more info from Maven site

Comment: for people who have more than one project this question could also be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531650/default-maven-compiler-setting

Comment: I put it in  <build><plugins></plugins></build> of pom file. It works, thanks!

Comment: I have something like `<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>` but I don't know the difference between it and your solution.

Answer (score 5):

artbristol gave the correct answer (and I upvoted him).

That was in 2012.  Here is an update more appropriate for today (2016, Java 8, Spring 4.x/Servlet 3.x):

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0</version>
   <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of this issue is Eclipse cannot resolve a valid value for the maven.compiler.source property when updating the `.classpath` file from the pom, it is simply using default one i.e

```
org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5.
```

**Just Add following properties into you `pom.xml` and update project:**

```
<properties>
            <javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
            <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Great answer, thx. This is the better solution in my case: Problems are shown in Eclipse but a maven build in the console works fine. Then I only need a hint for m2e and not an additional plugin-definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your brand new Maven project in Eclipse have JRE System Library version other than JavaSE-1.5. For that,find below jar in the following location.

- File: maven-compiler-plugin-3.1.jar
- Location:
  .m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-compiler-plugin\3.1

Then unzip the jar and locate "META-INF\maven\plugin.xml" which has four occurrences of `default-value="1.5"`. Replace all four `1.5` with `1.8` or whatever the version you want. You would know the rest of the process.
[Reference](https://sandocean.wordpress.com/2019/03/22/directly-generating-maven-projects-in-eclipse-with-java-version-newer-than-1-5/)