# Eclipse: JRE System Library in Java Build Path reset automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse as IDE. When I right click on the project, then click "Maven Update", my Java version changes to 1.5. Here is what I did so far:

1. I changed "Java build path" to "workspace default jre 1.8.0_25"
2. Then changed "java compiler" to 1.8
3. Then changed "project facets">java>1.8
4. Lastly Changed pom.xml java version to 1.8

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.3.v20140225</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I keep it to 1.8 version?

Comment: Someone please edit the post. I added some code but it is not showing. I don't know why.

Comment: For the code format issue, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252114/how-to-format-code-after-item-list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a typo in the groupId of the maven-compiler-plugin in your `pom.xml` file: it should be org.apache.maven.plugin**s**.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note that the `groupId` actually defaults to `org.apache.maven.plugins` so you could also omit it.

By default, the JRE used by m2e is 1.5, see this question : [Eclipse JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9926798/1743880)